# How to programmatically detect a (Samsung) foldable phone

Tags: android

How can one detect if your app is running on a foldable phone? Is there an api that can be called?

Looking at the docs of Configuration (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) I can not find any constants that can be probed to determine a foldable.

Unfortunately just listening to onConfigurationChanges is not enough for the app I am working on. To work correct we need to disable some features (I know, should not have to, but well that ship has sailed years ago ;)

Comment: Do you just want to detect changes - This is the way samsung reccomends it - https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/foldable/techdocs

Comment: I had found that page, indeed helpfull but does not answer my question alas.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think there is a practical way to do this - https://bitbar.com/blog/foldable-dual-screen-smartphones-are-coming-how-can-developers-respond/ Even Google sees foldable as an extension of screen continuity API. Maybe you could check the phone model name and compare it against the small number of foldables available. But I don't think that is a practical solution

Comment: Well in fact: for the few months that we need the solution till we have it fixed correctly this might be an option

Comment: maybe DisplayManager.getDisplays() always returns at least two or more Display on a foldable, something to test for. getDisplays() probably also returns multiple displays in MultiWindowMode, but as we do not support that in the app, it might work.

Comment: As far as I know there will only be one active display, and that's why DisplayManager returns only one at the time, even though their specs are different. Also when transitioning between screens, looks like it's just the activity being recreated. Sadly I don't have one to test all this. Some documentation: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/get-your-app-ready-for-foldable-phones.html

Comment: I checked the brand and model in the emulator with the Samsung foldable apk (makes me feel really dumb): printing "manufacturer ${Build.MANUFACTURER} - ${Build.MODEL}" gives: "manufacturer Google - Android SDK built for x86". If only I had a real device...

Comment: What do you need to disable?

Comment: have you looked at this doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/make-apps-fold-aware

Comment: @bluevoid, Can you please tell me if you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to check if a device is foldable

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_HINGE_ANGLE);
```

I have referred this from the google blog post https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/06/detecting-if-device-is-foldable-tablet.html